# "Bis später" vs. "Bis gleich"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Usually I say "***Bis später***" or "***Bis gleich***" interchangeably but I am wondering if there exists a situation in which I should use one in favour of another or vice verse.

So, is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the previous answers and some comments already show, opinions about the difference between these two words (and others with similar meaning) differ. That is because there is **no exact definition** of these terms. The only thing probably all would agree to is that *bis gleich* refers to a shorter time period than *bis später*.
So this list is just *my* personal usage:

- **Bis gleich**
  I would use this for very short times, a few minutes until about one hour. Up to about 30 minutes I would exclusively use *bis gleich*, no other one would fit.
- **Bis später**
  I would use this for times of a few hours. It also fits when you are not sure about how long it will be untill you meet again (might be a bit more than 30 minutes or 5 hours). I would rather not use it if I expect the next meeting to be many hours later (like today in the evening, when now it is still morning) and definitely not if the next meeting will be tomorrow.
- **Bis nachher**
  This is *almost* interchangeable with *bis später*, with the exception that it even fits less well with short times of about 2 hours.
- **Bis heute abend**
  This is the best choice if it is still early (morning or noon) and the next meeting will be in the evening.
- **Bis demnächst**
  This would be the best pick if the next meeting will probably be within the next few days. It would also fit if you are not sure whether if it will be today or tomorrow.
- **Bis dann**
  This is the most flexible one. It fits when you have already made a more or less concrete appointment (today 14:30, wednesday evening), then *dann* referrs to that particular point in time, but also when you have no clue when you will meet again. It is also the best for times that are too long for *bis gleich* but too short for *bis später* (like 1 - 2 hours).
- **Bis bald** (thanks to @infinitezero for pointig out that this one was missing)
  This is also quite flexible, it would fit for times from a couple of hours to approximately 1 or 2 weeks, *especially* if there is some uncertainty on when exactly you will meet again.

Comment: This is missing "bis bald"

Comment: Für mich ist der springende Punkt eher, dass _bis gleich_ eine enge Verknüpfung zwischen der Sprech*situation* und der Treff-Situation herstellt, die beiden sind sozusagen eine einzige Gesamtsituation. _Bis später_ verweist auf eines *Situationswechsel*. Dass sich dabei die zeitlichen Abstände unterscheiden, ist eher ein sachnotwendiger Zufall und nicht substantiell. Vgl. "Essen kommen!" - "Ja, gleich..." vs. "Ja, sofort....", beides abwehrend und ähnlich, aber im Erleben des Sprechers verschieden.

Comment: Ich wollte mit dem Essen-Kommen-Beispiel sagen: "ja, gleich" heißt jedenfalls "ich will jetzt nicht sofort kommen, lass mich erst noch das Spiel zu Ende spielen" (oder wie immer so eine Spielsituation heißt, bin kein Gamer). "Ja sofort" heißt: "Ich weiß, dass zu Recht von mir erwartet wird, dass ich unverzüglich antanze, nur leider geht das grad jetzt im Moment nicht so prompt". Praktisch läuft das auf dasselbe hinaus, aber psychologisch sind die Aussagen verschieden, die mit "sofort" ist ein halber (oder weniger) Entschuldigungsversuch.

Answer (score -1):

> So, is there any difference between the two?

The difference is in the amount of time expected to see the addressee again.

> > Bis gleich.

Means a very short amount of time, minutes or so.

> > Bis später.

Is used for a bigger amount of time, hours or even days.

> ... but I am wondering if there exists a situation in which I should use one in favour of another or vice verse.

*Bis später* could be used interchangeably with *Bis gleich* though. But not vice versa,

Comment: "Bis später could be used interchangeably though." - interchangeably with what?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper With _Bis gleich_ of course. But not vice versa.

Comment: Interchangeable ist m.W. kommutativ und besagt nichts darüber, welcher Teil der Ersetzte ist. A und B sind austauschbar heißt, man kann es so oder so machen, nicht nur so (wie?). Absolute Grenzen für "später" und "gleich" anzugeben halte ich für schwierig. V.a. würde ich behaupten, dass sich die Bereiche überlappen können, was ja auch Deine Aussage zum Interchangeable auszudrücken versucht.

Comment: Für andere Tage würde ich bis morgen/Mittwoch/dann verwenden aber niemals bis später.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I can't say it in English:

Wenn etwa beim Telefonieren klar ist, dass wir uns noch innerhalb der nächsten zwei, drei Stunden sehen werden, verabschiede ich mich mit *Bis gleich!* Meistens ist dann ein recht kurzes Zeitintervall bis zum Treffen gemeint. Wenn jemand z.B. mit der deutschen Bahn kommt und wenn ausgemacht ist, dass ich ihn/sie vom Bahnhof abhole, und wenn der Zug wieder Verspätung hat, dann bekomme ich irgendwann einen Anruf: "Ich bin in 10 Minuten da." Ich antworte dann "Alles klar, bis gleich!" "Bis später" wäre hier unpassend.

Wenn ganz unklar bleibt, wann (und ob überhaupt) ich den anderen oder die andere sehen werde, sage ich *Bis später!* Dann ist nichts ausgemacht, es ist für mich eine eher vage Absichtserklärung und ich fühle mich nicht strikt gebunden, es ist ein 'ich will versuchen, wieder Kontakt mit dir zu haben'. Man kann es aber auch als Zusage verstehen, es ist nicht eindeutig.

Es gibt noch *Bis nachher!* Das sage ich, wenn ein Treffen am selben Tag verabredet ist, also auch, wenn in einem Telefongespräch ausgemacht wird, dass wir uns z.B. um 17 Uhr zu einem Kaffee treffen wollen.

*Bis dann!* sage ich schließlich entweder als ganz unverbindlichen Abschied (= '*bis irgendwann*') oder mit einem "pronominal" gemeinten '*dann*': 'dann' = *der verabredete Zeitpunkt*.

In gleicher Bedeutung benutze ich *Bis dahin!*, vor allem, wenn noch einige Zeit bis zu dem verabredeten Treffen vergehen wird, aber auch, wenn ich einen Antwortkontakt zugesagt habe (*Bis dahin* = bis zu meiner zugesagten Antwort).

Comment: a) Bis später impliziert für mich schon, dass ein weiteres Treffen geplant ist und nicht bloß in Kauf genommen wird. b) Die Zeitspanne halte ich nicht für entscheidend. Man könnte mit jmd. per Zug verreisen, der andere ist schon dabei einzusteigen und redet währenddessen unaufhörlich auf einen ein. Man erspäht einen Süßwarenautomaten auf dem Bahnsteig und sagt: "Du, ich kauf noch Gummibärchen, bis später" und lässt ihn alleine den Koffer in den Wagen wuchten, während man sich zum Automaten sputet. Das "bis später" vertröstet, dass man nicht sogleich, sondern eben später weiter zuhören wird.

Comment: @userunknown Zustimmung zu a). Bei b) wäre das für mich aber ain klares "bis gleich", es sei denn, man wolle damit ausdrücken, dass man zwar in 5 Minuten wieder da ist, der andere aber bitter erst in ein paar Stunden damit fortfahren soll, einen zuzutexten.

Comment: @user unknown: Man kriegt das alles schwer zu fassen, nur mal folgendes Beispiel: "Du, ich muss jetzt Schluss machen, ich hab hier noch die Steuererklärung liegen, die muss heute noch raus. Jedenfalls schön, dass du dich gemeldet hast, hat mich echt gefreut. Ich sag jetzt einfach mal 'Bis später', okay?" - - - Man müsste sich typische Situationen ausdenken und dann fragen: Wie würdest du da sagen? Damit käme mehr herum als mit den hier (auch von mir) angestellten Spekulationen.

Comment: @RalfJoerres: Wichtig ist, nicht nur zu überlegen was man selbst sagen würde, sondern auch was man hören, also was andere sagen würden und sich keine Statististikfalle zu bauen, wonach man das sagen muss, was die meisten sagen würden. Ich meine, je nach üblichen Zeitintervallen kann "später" ein kürzeres oder ein längeres Zeitintervall bedeuten. In einer Unterhaltung, vielleicht am Telefon, wenn ein Düsenjäger über einen hinwegfliegt, sagt man eher "Moment" als "Später!", aber wenige Minuten Unterbrechung können schon als "später" zählen. "Das regeln wir später" dagegen zum Ende einer ...

Comment: ... Vorstandssitzung eines Vereins, der sich nur 2x im Jahr trifft, heißt "später" vielleicht nächstes oder übernächstes Mal, also in 6 oder 12 Monaten. "Gleich" würde man da aber nicht sagen.

Comment: @RalfJoerres: "Jedenfalls schön, dass du dich gemeldet hast, hat mich echt gefreut. Ich sag jetzt einfach mal 'Bis später', okay?" - "Okay, um wieviel Uhr soll ich nachher wieder anrufen? Habe dir ja noch so viel zu erzählen!" ;)

Comment: @user unknown: Das ist alles richtig, was Du schreibst. Was ich denke, steht nicht im Widerspruch dazu, ich hatte oben zu Volker Landgraf geschrieben, wie ich den Unterschied auffasse. Andere assoziieren anderes dazu, so ist das mit Sprache. Mit 'bis gleich' sage ich z.B., dass ich einen begonnenen Kontakt gewissermaßen nahtlos fortführe. Mit 'bis später' sage ich, dass ich davon ausgehe, dass ein angefangener Gesprächsfaden erst wieder reaktiviert werden muss, wenn wir nicht sowieso in eine andere Situation einsteigen, denn dazwischen kann ja einiges passieren, das ist einkalkuliert.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: - "Du Witzbold! Ich sag mal so: Netter Versuch, aber heute wird das wirklich nichts mehr. Das musst du mir dann alles die Tage erzählen, wenn ich ein bisschen mehr Luft habe. Und jetzt lass mich bitte hier weitermachen.Tschüssiee..." [_Ich werd' den Teufel tun und dem nochmal irgendwas mit 'bis' sagen..._]